# Is there a way to check a location and return the button Name at that location? C# GUI

Tags: c#, button, location

I currently am writing a program that uses buttons to create a grid in c#. I need to assign images to the buttons. However, while I know the location the image should start at, I cannot find a way to identify the button it should be tied to. The images move between buttons throughout the program as well. 
Using Windows Form Application.

buttons are initialized with generated code so its like this

```
        this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 30);
        this.button1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 3;
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

        this.button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 30);
        this.button2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 4;
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
```

I need a way to check the location (100,30) and be able to get button1;

Comment: Your question is confusing at best.  Maybe an example would help?

Comment: What is the UI framework? wpf? web? silverlight? winforms? something else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your actual problem is, but I *think* you want the button at a certain position in WinForms. Therefore you could use that code:

```
var yourLocation = new Point(100, 30);
var theButtonAtYourLocation = components.Components
    .Cast<Component>()
    .OfType<Button>()
    .FirstOrDefault(button => button.Location == yourLocation);
```

Of course it's possible that your location isn't precise for the button - then you could do something like:

```
var maxDifference = 10;
var yourLocation = new Point(100, 30);
var theButtonAtYourLocation = components.Components
    .Cast<Component>()
    .OfType<Button>()
    .FirstOrDefault(button => Math.Abs(button.Location.X - yourLocation.X) <= maxDifference &&
                              Math.Abs(button.Location.Y - yourLocation.Y) <= maxDifference);
```

Now it wouldn't be too difficult to get the name of that button:

```
var name = theButtonAtYourLocation?.Name;
```

The whole code has to be written into the *Code behind* of your form. you get there by pressing F7 when being in the designer.

I hope, I could help you.

Comment: This should be what I need. Haven't tested it yet, but it should work. Thanks.